# Sync between two dropbox accounts

Tags: dropbox

I have Dropbox account (X) that I upload backup files each 1 hours.

I have another Dropbox account (Y) that I want to "backup" my backup files from Dropbox X to Dropbox Y.

Is it possible to sync/transfer files between two Dropbox accounts automatically without using code?

Answer (score 1):

You might try [Microsoft Flows](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/shared_dropbox/dropbox/) to automate the process. This could look as follows:
[image: Microsoft Flow]

Here's a link to a template to achieve this:
[Copy files from one Dropbox account or folder to another](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/d291ea40409d11e6af0261d31dcd7275/copy-files-from-one-dropbox-account-or-folder-to-another/)

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as _accepted answer_.